# Django filter bool not iterable

Tags: django, filter, boolean, iterable

I want to filter all Relation Objects where (relation= following relation in a virtual community) the date one has initiated the following is in the past, related to the moment now.

The following declaration seems to be wrong, as a bool object is not iterable.
Is there another way to do that?

```
d = Relations.objects.filter(date_follow < datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt).

```
d = Relations.objects.filter(date_follow__lt=datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d = Relations.objects.filter(date_follow__lt=datetime.now())
```

Relevant documentation here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id7

Comment: thank you! it works. i'll also read the documentation (i've been looking for it all over the web, but i guess i wasn't giving the right keywords.)